# Coordinate system not working properly! OpenGL

Tags: opengl, java, textures, coordinates, lwjgl3

I am learning `opengl` and tried to add `texture` to a `rectangle` using `shaders` but unfortunately my `rectangle` is not displaying at correct location and changing the coordinate of the `rectangle` does not seem to change it's position but rather changes the size of `texture` applied. I'm using `opengl` 2.1. And here are my codes and screenshot of my problem.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;

import RenderEngine.Window;

public class Test {

    private int vertexShaderID;
    private int fragmentShaderID;
    private int programID;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().run();
    } 

    public void run() {
        Window.CreateWindow();

        float[] vertices = { 
                -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
                0.5f, 0.5f, 0f 
        };

        float[] texCoords = { 
                0f, 0f,
                0f, 1f,
                1f, 1f,
                1f, 0f 
        };

        short[] indices = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0 };

        int tex = loadTexture("res/image.png");

        int v_id = bindArrayBuffer(vertices);
        int t_id = bindArrayBuffer(texCoords);
        int i_id = bindIndices(indices);

        initShader();

        while(!Window.isCloseRequested()){
            Window.PollEvents();
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            GL11.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

            GL20.glUseProgram(programID);

            GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

            int loc = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, "samplr");
            if (loc != -1){
                GL20.glUniform1i(loc, 0);
            }

            GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, v_id);
            GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, t_id);
            GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, i_id);

            GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

            GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
            GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

            GL20.glUseProgram(0);

            Window.UpdateWindow();
        }

        GL20.glDetachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
        GL20.glDetachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
        GL20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
        GL20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);
        GL20.glDeleteProgram(programID);

        Window.CloseWindow();
    }

    public void initShader(){
        vertexShaderID = loadShader("src/shaders/vertexShader.glsl", GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        fragmentShaderID = loadShader("src/shaders/fragmentShader.glsl", GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        programID = GL20.glCreateProgram();
        GL20.glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
        GL20.glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
        GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
        GL20.glValidateProgram(programID);
        GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, 0, "position");
        GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, 1, "textures");
    }

    private int bindArrayBuffer(float[] vertices) {
        int b_id = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, b_id);
        FloatBuffer buffer = toFloatBuffer(vertices);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        return b_id;
    }

    private int bindIndices(short[] indices) {
        int b_id = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, b_id);
        ShortBuffer buffer = toShortBuffer(indices);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        return b_id;
    }

    private static ShortBuffer toShortBuffer(short[] data) {
        ShortBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createShortBuffer(data.length);
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }

    private static FloatBuffer toFloatBuffer(float[] data) {
        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }

    public int loadTexture(String fileName){
        BufferedImage bi;
        try {
            bi = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
            int width = bi.getWidth();
            int height = bi.getHeight();

            int[] pixel_raw = new int[width * height * 4];
            pixel_raw = bi.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);

            ByteBuffer pixels = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(width * height * 4);

            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
                    // 0xAARRGGBB
                    int pixel = pixel_raw[i * width + j];
                    pixels.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16 ) & 0xFF)); // RED
                    pixels.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));   // GREEN
                    pixels.put((byte) ((pixel) & 0xFF));    // BLUE
                    pixels.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));  // ALPHA
                }
            }

            pixels.flip();

            int id = GL11.glGenTextures();

            GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
            GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

            return id;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not load texture: " + fileName);
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public int loadShader(String file, int type) {
        StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                shaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Could not read file %s:", file));
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        int shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
        GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
        GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);
        if (GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
            System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID));
            System.err.println("Could not compile shader!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return shaderID;
    }

}
```

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 120

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 textures;

varying vec2 tex_coord;

void main()
{
    tex_coord = textures;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1);
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D samplr;

varying vec2 tex_coord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(samplr, tex_coord);
}
```

**Output**

[image: output with half size]

**When I change my vertices to:**

```
    float[] vertices = { 
        -1f, 1f, 0f,
        -1f, -1f, 0f,
        1f, -1f, 0f,
        1f, 1f, 0f 
    };
```

[image: output with full size]

**Without Texture**

[image: output without texture]

**Problem :**
For some reason `texCoords` is acting as `position` and `vertices` is acting as `textures` in `shaders`.

**Fix**
Apparently adding the `vertex` buffer to `attrib` index `1` fixes the problem.

```
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, t_id);
GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, v_id);
GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Even though `position` is binded to `attrib` location `0`.

```
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, 0, "position");
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, 1, "textures");
```

*Can anyone explain this?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling glBindAttribLocation you need to link your program again: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml